# How to save multiple small integers in one integer via bit shifting in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, bit-shift, application-settings, datastore

There are several lists of items. The number of the lists < 8. The number of items in any list < 16. User can select one item in each list. So we have a sequence of integers. For example: 9, 0, 12, 4.

There are any easy way to store user selection in one Integer (32 or 64) and reading it from there?

May be you know the more optimal way to store a sequence of 4-bit integers?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, define "optimal". Do you mean memory or performance? Storing numbers in one integer will be more memory efficient but slower. Storing each number in a type, which size equals a size of one word on the machine is faster, but less efficient.

Comment: You can use C's bit fields in structs.

Comment: Also, if lists can have a variable number of items in them, then you need to store a number of items as well. Since each item takes 4 bits, and max number of items is 16, 16 * 4 = 64, so there's no space for a number of items left. You'll need to store it separately.

Comment: Are you sure this optimization is worth it?

Comment: I need to store only the indexes of items of each list. This value(s) will be stored in database (CoreData). So using one attribute instead of 2 or even 8 seems to be more effective (for space of memory).

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (NSArray *)arrayFromLongint:(uint32_t)longint {
    uint8_t shortint;
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 32; i = i + 4) {
        shortint = longint >> i & 15; // 15 is 00001111 in binary
        [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:shortint]];
    }
    return array;
}

+ (uint32_t)longintFromArray:(NSArray *)array {
    uint8_t shortint, itemIndex = 0;
    uint32_t longint = 0;
    NSNumber *item;
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 32; i = i + 4) {
        if ([[array objectAtIndex:itemIndex] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
            item = [array objectAtIndex:itemIndex];
            shortint = [item unsignedShortValue] & 15; // 15 is 00001111 in binary
            longint = longint | shortint << i;
        }
        itemIndex++;
    }
    return longint;
}
```